# A word for someone who feigns ignorance

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word I remember looking up but can't remember. Something like:

When someone says something that's insulting but when you call them out on it, they pretend they don't know what was said was insulting. Instead, they argue that they meant it in a different context when they really didn't.

For example:

> A: "Wow *he's smart*"
>   B: "What do you mean *he's smart*?"
>   A: "What? I meant they're very intelligent."

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149368/discussion-on-question-by-lou-a-word-for-someone-who-feigns-ignorance); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I think [dissimulate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dissimulate?s=t) would work:

> verb (used with object), dis·sim·u·lat·ed, dis·sim·u·lat·ing.
>
> to disguise or conceal under a false appearance; dissemble: to dissimulate one's true feelings about a rival.

> verb (used without object), dis·sim·u·lat·ed, dis·sim·u·lat·ing.
>
> to conceal one's true motives, thoughts, etc., by some pretense; speak or act hypocritically.

In your example **A is dissimulating.** or alternatively you could use the synonym in the definition, **A is dissembling.**

But if you are looking for an adjective rather than a verb, you could say the person is **[disingenous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disingenuous)** -- in the sense of falsely or hypocritically ingenuous.

> adj lacking in frankness, candor, or sincerity; falsely or
>   hypocritically ingenuous; insincere: Her excuse was rather
>   disingenuous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing **passive-aggressive** behavior.

> **[Passive–aggressive behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior)** is characterized by indirect resistance to the demands of others and an avoidance of direct
>   confrontation.

[Here's](https://www.liveyourtruestory.com/examples-of-passive-aggressive-behaviour-communication/) a description of one of the symptoms of passive-aggressive behavior:

> On the other extreme, insincere compliments are a very sneaky way to
>   throw in some nasty insults. They are hoping that you will react badly
>   to the insult. The intention being that if you say anything about the
>   cheap insult, they will tell you that you misinterpreted them, and
>   they were only trying to pay you a compliment. Then you doubt yourself
>   and, if anyone else was present, your behaviour looks unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a form of verbal [**plausible deniability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability).

The first sentence ("Wow, he's smart") is said with enough tone and inflection to imply sarcasm, yet the literal contents of the sentence, the words, are innocuous enough. It leaves the speaker with the possibility of denying the insult implied by tone. That is, any denial of the intention to cause offence is **plausible** or believable.

Comment: I've seen this used in politics  and espionage; I am not sure it is suitable for petty office bickering.

Answer (score 1):

Obtuse? It's often used in the phrase "deliberately obtuse".

See the example in definition 1 from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> **obtuse**
>   Annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand.
>   *‘he wondered if the doctor was being deliberately obtuse’*
>
> Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obtuse

Comment: ... but this only works when "deliberately" is in front of it. Otherwise, this is the _opposite_ of what OP is looking for. Someone who is obtuse is _not_ feigning ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these will do.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disingenuous

> 3. Assuming a pose of naïveté to make a point or for deception.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicitous

> 1. Given to or marked by deliberate deceptiveness in behavior or speech.

~fie

Answer (score 0):

Ignorance is the act of ignoring, not unknowing. One is ignorant when he has learned and chooses to ignore. Dumb means lacking intelligence. Stupid typifies one does not know or has not yet learned.

So, why would one pretend (feign) to ignore in an effort to appear innocent? Seems to me the correct phrase would be feigning innocence, not ignorance.

[www.merriam-webster.com › dictionary › ignorant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignorant)

[www.merriam-webster.com › dictionary › dumb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dumb)

Comment: The dictionary definition of ignorance doesn't support the narrow definition you've applied.