# What is an adjective to describe someone deliberately feigning ignorance?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is their an adjective that describe the behaviour of people who deliberately feign ignorance of something to avoid blame or accusation.

For example:

> A: Hey, I saw you laugh with your buddies at that person who walked past. You shouldn’t make fun of people.
>
> B: I wasn’t laughing at that person, I was admiring their shoes. If you thought I was laughing, it must be because *you* think there is something funny about them!
>
> A: Come on you know exactly what you were doing.

I know it's lying but I feel like there might be a single word that describes that specific type of feigning ignorance.

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470034/a-word-for-someone-who-feigns-ignorance). Specifically *obtuse* and *disingenuous*.

Answer (score 1):

A word not given in the question [linked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470034/a-word-for-someone-who-feigns-ignorance) in comment is

> **prevaricate**
> to avoid telling the truth or saying exactly what you think

from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prevaricate). The [noun form](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prevarication) is

> **prevarication**
> the fact of avoiding telling the truth or saying exactly what you think

Comment: Although this is technically correct, I suspect that it would be misunderstood because, as the OED remarks of prevaricate, *b. intransitive. To behave evasively or indecisively so as to delay action; to procrastinate.* **Now the usual sense.**

Comment: @Greybeard it isn't the *adjective* requested either. However the word came to mind so I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a single word, but you can call it **playing dumb.** [MacMillan defines this as:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/play-act-dumb)

> to pretend to not know or not understand something